# 403 - Access is denied after authenticating

Tags: spring-security

Greetings!

When I try authenticating against my existing db I'm getting authenticated but I get the 403 page. If I just tried a wrong password I get 'wrong credentials' message as expected.
I tried authenticating per sample app included with SpringSecurity and that worked fine.

security-context.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"></global-method-security>

    <http auto-config="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_TEST" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <form-login
            login-page="/login/index.jsp"
            default-target-url="/admin/test.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login/index.jsp?login_error=1" />  
    </http>

    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcUserService">      
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source system-wide="n103df"/>
        </password-encoder>        
    </authentication-provider>


    <beans:bean id="jdbcUserService"  class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username,authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?" />
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username,password,enabled as enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
        <beans:property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="" />

    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.providers.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>
```

Will appreciate any help :-)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are getting a 403 code, it means that the user does not have the required roles. So, athentication is not the problem, is authorization.
The only way to know what is going on is to put logging level to debug, there should be more info. Post it here.
Does your roles have the 'ROLE_' prefix?

Answer (score 2):

... figured it out. Despite having ROLE_TEST specified in the config file and the same in the 'authority' column of the db, Spring-Sec was expecting ROLE_SUPERVISOR:

```
[DEBUG,AbstractSecurityInterceptor,http-8084-7] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/test.jsp; ConfigAttributes: [ROLE_TEST]
[DEBUG,AbstractSecurityInterceptor,http-8084-7] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@af840ed7: Principal: org.springframework.security.userdetails.User@3ec100: Username: testUser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERVISOR; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 350B260FAFDDBF04D5CB4AAAB7B8A441; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERVISOR
[DEBUG,ExceptionTranslationFilter,http-8084-7] Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:68)
```

... now I'm curious, how come?
So after changing ROLE_TEST to ROLE_SUPERVISOR in the config file all worked as expected.

Comment: .... I realized today that all this time I was looking at the wrong db, 'nough said.
Thaks a bunch though, it did help!